# Spring Cloud API Gateway routing does not work using NetFlix Eureka Registry

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to create a custom route on the gateway, to have control over which microservices the gateway will be able to distribute and it doesn't work.

In this process I use the Registry Eureka, Gateway e microservice Seguranca.

spring boot 3.1.5
java 17

Custom route in GateWay:

```
server:
    port: 8080

spring:
    application:
        name: gateway
    cloud:
        gateway:
            routes:
            - id: seguranca
              uri: lb://seguranca
              predicates:
                  - Path=/api/**

eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultzone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

---

microservice seguranca:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: seguranca
```

controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final TokenService tokenService;

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity authenticate(@RequestBody @Valid LoginRecord loginRecord) {

        var authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRecord.username(), loginRecord.password());
        var authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);

        var tokenJWT = tokenService.createToken((UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new DataTokenJWT(tokenJWT));
    }

}
```

---

Registry:

```
eureka:
    client:
        fetch-registry: false
        register-with-eureka: false
    instance:
        hostname: localhost
server:
    port: 8761
spring:
    application:
        name: service-registry
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXCHW.png)

I added discovery, it works but I realized that custom rotates don't work

```
            discovery:
              locator:
                  enabled: true
                  lower-case-service-id: true
```